# Best Japanese language learning system?

Tags: learning

I have a friend who speaks Japanese and I would like to learn the language with no prior experience.  What commercial teaching approach would you consider the best?  Pimsleur, Phonics,  or something else?

Comment: Good on you for wanting to learn Japanese, and thanks for joining Japanese Language and Usage. Unfortunately, this question is off-topic, for reasons explained [here](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/798/91). There's a [post](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/756/91) on the meta site on resources for learning Japanese, and you can discuss learning techniques, and anything else within reason, in the chat room, even though it's off-topic here. Feel free to ask other questions on the Japanese Language and Usage web site in the future. Ganbatte! (Don't give up!)

Comment: I upvoted this question to help get you the required 20 reputation to use chat. (But it's off-topic).

Comment: et al to what? Who is referred and who is not?

Comment: -1 to counteract the misused upvote. Not that the question is particularly bad.

Comment: Sawa, I refer to other knowledgeable commenters here, and not to observers.
Andrew Grimm, many thanks, I will return.

Comment: "et al.," is unnecessary as it is a salutation. It would have been edited and removed.

Comment: careful, phonics is something very easy to get hooked on.

Comment: @sawa, by downvoting just for the sake of counteracting, you have also misused the downvote. You should have flagged the comment instead.